# Can't pass state in React router link

Tags: reactjs

I have a notification bubble that is supposed to link to a chat interface.

I am trying to pass the state for the chat in the link that the bubble is in, but no luck.

```
class NotifBubble extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.pathname = "/chat/" + this.props.merchant.id
        if (this.props.merchant.id === 0) {
            this.pathname = '#';
        }

    }

    render() {
        if (typeof this.props.merchant === 'undefined') {
            return <div></div>
        }
        return (
            <Link className="notif-bubble-link" to={{
                pathname: this.pathname,
                state: { merchant: this.props.merchant }
            }}><div className="notif-bubble slide-in-right">
                    {this.props.message}
                </div></Link>
        );
    }
}

export default NotifBubble;
```

Everything is working correctly - up to the point where I pass the state, this.props.merchant, into the link. this.props.merchant is absolutely correct though.

What am I doing wrong here to not pass state correctly?

Comment: Instead of `state` try `query`.

Comment: No luck here either - I'm not seeing any query values

Comment: Pathname is correctly set, but state is not

Comment: Is `this.props.merchant` is object?

Comment: It is, though I've tried passing just a string, and it also did not work

Comment: Do simple debug, use sample state(as { example: 'myState' }) in the `Link` component and listen the state with console.log(this.props) in render function.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `this.pathname` to store your component state. Use the [React State API](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) provided.

Also it is preferred to initialize the state in the constructor (as opposed to `componentWillMount`)

```
class NotifBubble extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const pathname = props.merchant.id === 0 ?
      '#' : `/chat/${props.merchant.id}`;

    this.state = {
      pathname
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (typeof this.props.merchant === 'undefined') {
      return <div > < /div>
    }
    return ( <
      Link className = "notif-bubble-link"
      to = {
        {
          pathname: this.state.pathname,
          state: {
            merchant: this.props.merchant
          }
        }
      } > < div className = "notif-bubble slide-in-right" > {
        this.props.message
      } <
      /div></Link >
    );
  }
}

export default NotifBubble;
```

Comment: Same problem, the state is undefined when clicking the link

Comment: I've replaced my entire component with yours, and no luck

Comment: are you talking about the `state` property of your `Link` component ? If that is the case, can you post the code for the `Link` component ?

Comment: The Link component is from React Router

Comment: But yes, I am talking about the state property of the Link component. I am passing in the data - and it is definitely being passed in correctly, but it isn't in the component linked to

Comment: How do you access the state in your destination component ?

Comment: this.props.location.state.merchant

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell, it SHOULD work, it's just not working.

Answer (score 0):

To pass object, you need to `stringify` the object first,

```
<Link className="notif-bubble-link" 
    to={{pathname: this.pathname,
         state: { merchant: JSON.stringify(this.props.merchant)}
       }}>
   <div className="notif-bubble slide-in-right">
         {this.props.message}
   </div>
</Link>
```

To access `state` do this,

```
const merchant = JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.merchant)
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work either. And I've passed in non-serialized objects before too.

Answer (score 0):

When using a pathname url that contains search parameters or hash parameters like this: `/link?id=100` or `/link#some-id` then it won't pass the state object to the next route unless you move the parameters to their own designated properties like this:

```
        <Link to={{
            pathname: '/link',
            search: '?id=100',
            hash: '#some-id',
            state: {
              id: 100,
            }
        }}>
          Click here
        </Link>
```

Hope that helps anyone who has a url with search or hash parameters. [link to React-Router docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

Answer (score 0):

Should be sent like this `<Link to="new-path" state={{ some: "value" }} />`